# return both count and list from DAO

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm writing a web app where I need to return the total number of rows from the Servlet to my JSP.

I'm unable to know how can I send the `count` attribute to my JSP along with `userBeans`.

Below is my code.

**Servlet**

```
package org.servlet;

import org.DAO.*;
import org.bean.UserBean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/GetData")
public class GetData extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GetData() {
        super();
    }

    GetDataDAO getdatadao = null;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // set content type

        try {
            getdatadao = new GetDataDAO();
            List<UserBean> userBeans = getdatadao.list();
            int count = getdatadao.getTheCount();
            request.setAttribute("userBeans", userBeans);
            request.setAttribute("count", count);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("GetCaseData.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**JSP:**

```
<div class="status">
        <span class="totalTime"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="Submit" value="Get Case" name="getCase" id="getCase"
            disabled="disabled" />
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>Case Number</td>
                <td><input id="caseNumber" name="caseNumber" type="text"
                    value="${userBeans[0].getCaseNumber()}" /></td>

                <td>Case Owner</td>
                <td><input id="caseOwner" name="caseOwner" type="text"
                    value="${userBeans[0].getCaseOwner()}" /></td>
            </tr>
```

I want this `count` value to be in `<span class="totalTime"></span>`. Please let me know how can I do this.

I know that this can be done with the below.

```
<span class="totalTime"><%=request.getAttribute("count")%></span>
```

But i don't want to include any java code in my JSP, but do it in just the standard MVC way.

Please let me know how can I get this done.

Thanks

Comment: What's the difference btw userBeans and count?  I mean can't you do a `${count}`?

Comment: Are you using JSTL or any EL expression parser?

Comment: Hi @RC., this worked. Thanks :-)